# How to find percentages of a column with characters

Tags: r, percentage, crosstab

I have a large `data set` titled `credit_long` with one of the columns being `DEFAULT`, I want to know how many are `yes` and how many are `no`. I have not been able to solve this because the column is set up as `yes/no` rather than `numeric`.

I tried using

```
as.numeric(as.factor(credit_long$DEFAULT))
```

with no luck.

Comment: `table(credit_long$DEFAULT)`.

Answer (score 0):

As @Gregor commented, using:

```
table(credit_long$DEFAULT)
```

will give you counts for each available option. To convert this to a percentage you could do:

```
table(credit_long$DEFAULT)[1]/nrow(credit_long)
table(credit_long$DEFAULT)[2]/nrow(credit_long)
```